# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

whenever i run this code get the error are as bellow.
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
i m also try this statement img.crossorigin= "anonymous" but not get proper output,if any one knows then help me.

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/chromagallery.css">
      <style type="text/css">

    body,html{height: 100%;}
    .content
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }

    .chroma-gallery-logo
    {
        width: 300px;
        height: 124px;
        background: url(images/chromagallery_logo.png) no-repeat;
        margin: 25px auto;
    }

    .mygallery{margin: 25px 0;} 

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) /* small logo */ 
    {
      .chroma-gallery-logo
      {
        width: 200px;
        height: 83px;
        background-size:200px 83px;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 980px) /* Desktop */ 
    {
      .content {width: 60%;}
    }   

     </style>
     <title>Chroma Gallery</title>
         </head>
         <body>

<div class="chroma-gallery-logo"></div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="chroma-gallery mygallery">
        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="Pic 1" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Pic 2" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="Pic 3" data-largesrc="images/3.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="Pic 4" data-largesrc="images/4.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="Pic 5" data-largesrc="images/5.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="Pic 6" data-largesrc="images/6.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" alt="Pic 7" data-largesrc="images/7.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/8.jpg" alt="Pic 8" data-largesrc="images/8.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" alt="Pic 9" data-largesrc="images/9.jpg">
        <img src="images/thumbs/10.jpg" alt="Pic 10" data-largesrc="images/10.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modernizr-chrg.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/chromagallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".mygallery").chromaGallery();
    });
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your browser might be blocking imageData on local content.  That's what it appears to be based on the "images/.." urls.  There are two things you could do.

1. Try a different browser.  Firefox has a different policy than Safari/Chrome on local data.  View your page in Firefox and see if there's a difference.
2. Serve your page over an internet connection to make the browser kick in a different policy.  If you have python open a command line and go to the folder of your project.  Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` and open a browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/yourpage.html`  to see if that works.

The browser doesn't like code from different places accessing image data. You either need to convince the browser that the code is coming from the same place or have the servers send a special header allowing the cross-origin.

Comment: thanks @wolfhammer,its works on Firefox but not in Google chrome.your information is very helpful.if you have any option other than python ,please tell me.